# get text of multiple span using class selector

Tags: jquery

I have page wherein there are multiple span tags having same css class applied.
I wanna get text of all these span tags. 
I used $('.clsname').text();
But the problem is, it returns all span tags text as a single string.
I need it to a array / seperated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var text = [];
$('.clsname').each(function(){
    text.push( $(this).text());
});
```

`.each()` Iterates over all selected elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
  var arr = [];
  $('.clsname').each(function(){
      arr.push($(this).text());
   });
```